# Add a value every ith number in a column

Tags: r

My data.frame `Analysis` is 105,000 obs of 3 variables. Consider the following a shortened example, with the `Height` of different `FlowerColours` recorded over `Time`:

```
Height <- c(10, 12, 11, 12, 16, 17, 16, 16, 9, 9, 10, 12)
FlowerColours <- c("Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Red", "Red",
              "Red", "Red", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow")
Time <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
Analysis <- data.frame(Height, FlowerColours, Time, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I wish to add in a new column, `Analysis$Paddock`, that would add a different value for each `Paddock` every third occurrence of `FlowerColours` but am unsure how to do so? For example:

```
Analysis$Paddock <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

This seems rather simple but I have been unable to find a similar example... and becoming very frustrated at myself! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Analysis$Paddock <- with(Analysis, ave(seq_along(FlowerColours), 
     FlowerColours,FUN=function(x) as.numeric(gl(length(x),
         2, length(x)))))

Analysis$Paddock
#[1] 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Analysis)[, Paddock:= cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Time) <0)), by = FlowerColours]
```

Or can replace `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Time) <0))` with `ceiling(seq_len(.N)/2)`

Comment: @user2716568 No problem.  Another option would be to use `%/%`